# Create NSDictionary-backed objects

Tags: iphone, objective-c, dictionary, nsdictionary

I want to create a "business object" based on a `NSDictionary`. The reason for this is that I want implementations to be able to extend this object with arbitrary keys, and another reason is that I am persisting it using the convenient plist format (the objects stored are either integers, floats or strings).

The business object contains a number of predefined properties, e.g.

```
@property NSString* customerName;
@property NSString* productCode;
@property int count;
@property double unitPrice;
```

I want to serialize this, for example to a property list (this is not a strict requirement, it could be some other easy-to-use format). Preferably, the implementation of the class should be just

```
@synthesize customerName, productCode, count, unitPrice:
```

for the example above. To use this class, I want to do something like:

```
MyBusinessObject* obj = [MyBusinessObject businessObjectWithContentsOfFile:fileName];
obj.productCode = @"Example";
[obj setObject:@"Some data" forKey:@"AnExtendedProperty"];
[obj writeToFile:fileName atomically:YES];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "path of least resistance" turned out to be using `NSCoding` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You should make your class KVC complaint. KVC does the magic. [Look](http://theocacao.com/document.page/161/) here.Ex,

```
   // assume inputValues contains values we want to
// set on the person

NSDictionary * inputValues;
YOURCLASS    * person = [[YOURCLASS alloc] init];

[person setValuesForKeysWithDictionary: inputValues];
```

Comment: Good point! My class has rudimentary KVC compliance (no validation etc). But how do I go from there to -and from- a plist? I guess that is the core of my question. EDIT: I guess going *from* a plist is harder, but I don't need that for this case.

Comment: @Krumelur I'm not sure how wedded you are to property lists, but the normal thing to do would be to implement `NSCoding`. You can then use `NSKeyedArchiver` to get an `NSData` representation of your object in binary plist format.

Comment: What's a "KVC complaint"?  ;)

Comment: @Tommy I think I'm going the `NSCoding` way, creating a base class. No reason to use property lists, other than they were used in my prototype. Put it as an answer and I will accept it :)